# Redirect when buying products from a certain product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

I have this code:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect');
function woo_custom_redirect( $redirect ) {

if (
    ! is_user_logged_in()       
    && (is_checkout())
    ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/my-account/edit-account/' ) );
    return $redirect;
    }
}
```

How can I replace the redirection condition when I make an order to purchase a product from a certain category?

For example, if a user purchases a product from a certain category, then when he attempts to place an order, he redirects to registration and back, after successful registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will redirect to my account page the non logged user in checkout page when they have an item from a specific product category. You will have to define in the code your specific product category:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect');
function woo_custom_redirect( $redirect ) {
    // HERE set your product category (can be term IDs, slugs or names)
    $category = 'posters';

    $found = false;

    // CHECK CART ITEMS: search for items from our product category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found = true; 
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && $found ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: If I add `return 'domain.com/cart/';` will this be the right decision to return to the cart after registration?

Comment: @Dmitry template_redirect hook is not a filter, but an action hook… so you don't have to return anything… also after a redirection exit(); is needed and mandatory

Comment: How can I automatically return to the shopping cart?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this recently and this solution worked for me. This solution checks what product categories the items are in, in the order details once the order has been received. So the redirect will take place after payment has been made.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout' );
function woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout() {
  global $wp;
 
  if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
  
  $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ); 
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );  
  $prod_category = [CAT ID OR SLUG];

  foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

    if( has_term( $prod_category, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
        // change below to the URL that you want to send your customer to
         $redirect_url = 'https://www.example.com/custom-thank-you/';

         wp_redirect($redirect_url );

        exit;
      }
    }   
  }
}
```